# disable bourbon radial gradient fallback color?

Tags: css, sass, mixins, fallback, bourbon

I'd rather not have the fallback applied whilst using the radial gradient mixin in Bourbon.

The documentation http://bourbon.io/docs/#radial-gradient says it's optional, but whatever I try, the primary colour always gets applied (I've tried entering false, null or none as $fallback).

Any tip greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the radial-gradient mixin, I believe that the fallback value allows you to specify either a colour or "transparent". If you don't specify a fallback it uses the first colour that you provide it.

To your question, I believe specifying transparent against the fallback should solve your problem.

For example:

```
@include radial-gradient(#1e5799, #3dc3d1, $fallback: transparent);
```

Comment: Thanks. Providing transparent as fallback still acts as an overwrite of previous styles and I'd rather not do that (the last thing I want is to have !important all over). Seems like I'll have to make my own mixin then!